# Change boolean value on Parse via UIButton?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

How can I change the boolean value of my Parse class named "shoppingCart" by clicking a button?

```
@IBAction func addToCart(sender: AnyObject) {

    var cartObjectStatus = itemObject.valueForKey("shoppingCart") as! Bool!
    cartObjectStatus = false

}
```

Comment: What does the relevant Parse documentation say on the topic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
itemObject.setBool(false, forKey: "shoppingCart")
```

The problem with your original attempt is that you're setting the value of the **local variable** to **false**. Using the above **setBool** method will alter the object's variable.

**Edit** - If PFObject doesn't support `setBool`, you'll have to go with `setValue:forKey`:

```
itemObject.setValue(false, forKey: "shoppingCart")
```

This is a method on NSObject, which PFObject has to derive from.

Comment: Yeah I thought that would work as well, but PFObject does not have setBool property.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `setValueForKey` on the `itemObject`. When you get the `bool` with `valueForKey` it's passed by value, not reference, so changing it like you are will not update `itemObject`'s version of it.

I suggest reading both Parse documentation and some tutorial on Swift basics.